# Tailwind CSS for Shopify theme | tailwind build is not working

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I am trying to generate css code by compiling tailwind base, components and utilities to develop Shopify theme.

Below is my files.

**tailwind.config.json**

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**application.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**Executing below code:**

```
npx tailwindcss build -i  src/styles/application.css -o src/styles/tailwind.css
```

**Screenshot as Below**

[terminal screenshot after running above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pQOm.png)

Please let me know for more information on this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is your file structure? Where is tailwind config and where are the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your HTML and JavaScript files in `src` folder? 
Make sure your to separate your tailwindcss file and `html js` for better code structure understanding.

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./the folder where your html,js files exits/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I figured the way by pointing the folders correctly.